# I’m not sure if this mathematical formulation for normal force is correct

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, vectors, constrained-dynamics

Consider an arbitrarily defined surface

$$f(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^3$$

The normal vector to any given point on the graph of f is given by the gradient of f. Since the normal force at a point on the surface is the unit normal vector to the surface at that point, wouldn’t a reasonable definition then be:

$$F_{n}(x,y)=\frac{\nabla f(x,y)}{||\nabla f(x,y)||}$$

Is this right?

Comment: The gradient gives the normal if the surface is defined implicitly by the equation $f(x,y,z)=0$. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)#Calculating_a_surface_normal). Also, you get the direction of the normal force right in this case, but the normal force needs correct magnitude and units. That depends on other forces present, e.g. gravity.

Comment: Force Normal to the surface is dot product of force at a  point on surface with unit normal vector found using gradient.